# Fill a multidimensional array with date if don't exist into the array with PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have this multidimensional array in PHP:

```
Array
(
    [47] => Array
        (
            [2019-02-24] => Array
                (
                    [AVA_Id] => 1
                    [AVA_Status] => Open
                )
            [2019-02-25] => Array
                (
                    [AVA_Id] => 3
                    [AVA_Status] => Open
                )
            [2019-02-28] => Array
                (
                    [AVA_Id] => 4
                    [AVA_Status] => Close
                )
        )
    [48] => Array
        (
            [2019-02-26] => Array
                (
                    [AVA_Id] => 2
                    [AVA_Status] => Open
                )
        )
)
```

How for a known date range I can fill this array with missing dates ?

My date range is the following:

```
Array ( [0] => 2019-02-24 [1] => 2019-02-25 [2] => 2019-02-26 [3] => 2019-02-27 [4] => 2019-02-28 [5] => 2019-03-01 [6] => 2019-03-02 )
```

For example, for array wit the key `47`, I would need to add missing date: 2019-02-26, 2019-02-27, 2019-03-01 and 2019-03-02 because these dates are into the range of dates but not into the array under the key `47`. Same thing for the key `48`.

My try was this one:

```
foreach($daterange as $date){
    $date = $date->format('Y-m-d');
    if(in_array($myarray[$date]))
        $newarray[$date] = $myarray[$date];
    else
        $newarray[$date] = 0;
}
```

Comment: What values (`AVA_Id` and `AVA_Status`) do you want to add for the missing dates, or do you just want an empty array?

Comment: Hello @Nick, `AVA_Id` could be `0` and `AVA_Status` could be `no`. Thanks for your help.

Comment: instead of `in_array` use `isset`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you need to loop through each element of your array, and then check whether each date is present as a key in the array. If it isn't, we add a "blank" element for that date:

```
foreach ($array as &$arr) {
    foreach ($dates as $date) {
        if (!in_array($date, array_keys($arr))) {
            $arr[$date] = array('AVA_Id' => 0, 'AVA_Status' => 'no');
        }
    }
}
print_r($array);
```

The output is quite long so I've omitted it but you can see it in this [demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/ve9os)

To sort the array keys by date, just add a `ksort` to the loop:

```
foreach ($array as &$arr) {
    foreach ($dates as $date) {
        if (!in_array($date, array_keys($arr))) {
            $arr[$date] = array('AVA_Id' => 0, 'AVA_Status' => 'no');
        }
    }
    ksort($arr);
}
```

[demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/rmf0h)

**Update**

As pointed out in the comments by @trincot, the above can be written more efficiently using `isset` rather than `in_array`:

```
foreach ($array as &$arr) {
    foreach ($dates as $date) {
        $arr[$date] = isset($arr[$date]) ? $arr[$date] : array('AVA_Id' => 0, 'AVA_Status' => 'no');
    }
    ksort($arr);
}
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/VXrDG)

Or using the NULL coalescing operator `??` in PHP7 upwards:

```
foreach ($array as &$arr) {
    foreach ($dates as $date) {
        $arr[$date] = $arr[$date] ?? array('AVA_Id' => 0, 'AVA_Status' => 'no');
    }
    ksort($arr);
}
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/UubpV)

**Update 2**

The code can be made even more efficient by using a temporary array in the loop, which removes the need for `ksort`:

```
foreach ($array as &$arr) {
    foreach ($dates as $date) {
        $out[$date] = $arr[$date] ?? array('AVA_Id' => 0, 'AVA_Status' => 'no');
    }
    $arr = $out;
}
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/ENPQt)

**Note**

As has been pointed out by @dWinder, you can use `array_diff` between the `$dates` array and the keys of each array element to find the new entries that are required:

```
foreach ($array as &$arr) {
    foreach (array_diff($dates, array_keys($arr)) as $date) {
        $arr[$date] = array('AVA_Id' => 0, 'AVA_Status' => 'no');
    }
    ksort($arr);
}
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/a3EeJ)

Comment: I would prefer use `array_diff` to get the key to set

Comment: @dWinder good idea! If you don't plan to add that as an answer I'll include it in mine?

Comment: Looks working very well. How in the same time I can order the date by ASC? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Go ahead - you answer is good - I prefer 1 great answer then 3 separate. And add also `ksort`

Comment: @dWinder I was 14 seconds ahead of you on the ksort! :-)

Comment: If you have to do this a lot with large files, my answer is faster. This code searches two arrays on every single element, which is inefficient. If it is a small dataset then don't worry.

Comment: @dWinder I've added the `array_diff` idea. It'd be interesting to benchmark to see if the cost of `array_diff` is more than all the `in_array` calls

Comment: Thanks @Nick and @dWinder. Helps me a lot. So we don't use `array_diff` here?

Comment: @PacPac for large data sets I think the `array_diff` is probably going to be faster.

Comment: @lufc yes, I like your use of `array_fill_keys` and basically turning the problem on its head. As to whether it's faster than the `array_diff` solution I think that would need to be benchmarked. Anyway +1 to you...

Comment: @Nick - the ksort alone would result in huge differences. With my approach you ksort once. With yours you ksort n times.

Comment: @lufc well that's why I've suggested that OP should benchmark both and why I also upvoted your answer. Probably OP should change the accept...

Comment: In fact you don't need any ksort on mine as the original date range array was already sorted :)

Comment: @lufc agreed. To be fair though, there isn't really that much of a need to ksort as it just makes the data prettier for display. Any attempt to access the array elements via a given date index will work regardless of whether the keys are sorted or not.

Comment: @PacPac I've added some more efficient code (especially the version under **Update 2**). I hope it's useful to you.

Answer (score 1):

Why not start with a blank array of date ranges and then copy your actual elements into this array.

```
$template = array_fill_keys($daterange,['AVA_Id' => 0,'AVA_Status' => 'No']);

foreach ($outer as $ind => $dates) {

   $output[$ind] = $template;

   foreach ($dates as $d => $v) {

       $output[$ind][$d] = $v;

   }

 }
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/llvd0)

Comment: @PacPac if you have a big dataset it would be worth benchmarking this answer against mine you might well find it is faster.

Comment: Hello lufc, do I need to use ksort() function to sort the dates ASC ?

Comment: No you do not need to ksort as your `$daterange` was already sorted and this maintains that ordering. This is also much more efficient than the accepted answer.